# Programmatically login via form post and use credentials for another request

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I need to login via form post in c# but then I need to use the cookies that get set in my next request to access secure data.

The initial part is pretty simple:

```
string URLAuth = "https://mywservice.com/login";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
            formData["Username"] = "email@domain.com";
            formData["Password"] = "password";

            byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URLAuth, "POST", formData);
            string resultAuthTicket = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
            webClient.Dispose();
```

I have this part working but how do I store and use that in an immediate next request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think WebClient is the wrong choice here; I would use System.Net.HttpWebRequest instead. That will give you direct access to the headers that come back in the response to your credential post, and then you can copy whatever headers (including the cookie header) onto your next HttpWebRequest to get what you're really after.